# How to display recursive menu or nested set model in fatfree framework

Tags: recursion, fat-free-framework

How to display recursive menu or nested set model in fatfree framework ,  I am have categories table

> (id,cat_name, alias,prarent_id,published)

can you help me show it in template

Answer (score 0):

For recursion, you can take advantage of the [with](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#Include) attribute of the `<include>` directive.

```xml
//menu.html
<ul>
  <repeat group="$cats" value="$cat">
    <li>
      {{@cat.name}}
      <include href="menu.html" if="@cat.children" with="cats={{@cat.children}}"/>
    </li>
  </repeat>
</ul>
```

But for this to work, you need first to arrange your data hierarchically in your controller:

```php
$rows=$db->exec('SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY parent_id,weight');
$cats=$refs=array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $id=$row['id'];
  if ($parent=$row['parent_id']) {
    $i=count($refs[$parent]['children']);
    $refs[$parent]['children'][$i]=$row+array('children'=>array());
    $refs[$id]=&$refs[$parent]['children'][$i];
  } else {
    $cats[$id]=$row+array('children'=>array());
    $refs[$id]=&$cats[$id];
  }
}
$f3->set('cats',$cats);
echo Template::instance()->render('menu.html');
```

NB: it gives better control to have a weight column in your table, hence the `ORDER BY parent_id,weight`. Replace it by `ORDER BY parent_id` if you don't need that column.